# Terrain elevations not visible

Tags: openlayers-3, cesiumjs

I have created an Openlayers 3 map as below:

```
this.map = new ol.Map({
.....
});
```

Switched it to ol3cesium globe by below:

```
this.ol3d = new olcs.OLCesium({ map: this.map });
this.ol3d.setEnabled(false);
```

Till here , my code works fine. It switched from 2D to 3D.

Now i want elevations on my map. For which i wrote below:

```
var scene = this.ol3d.getCesiumScene();    
var terrainProvider = new Cesium.CesiumTerrainProvider({
  url: 'http://assets.agi.com/stk-terrain/world'
});
scene.terrainProvider = terrainProvider;
```

But i can't see any elevations. I don't get any runtime errors also.
How do i get get elevations?

Comment: try this url `url : '//cesiumjs.org/stk-terrain/tilesets/world/tiles'`

Comment: Even better would be to use //assets.agi.com/stk-terrain/v1/tilesets/world/tiles.  cesiumjs.org just does a redirect to the assets.agi.com endpoint.  I'm not seeing anything odd with your sample code from a Cesium stand point.  If you zoom to a mountainous area (e.g. "Half Dome") and tilt the camera, can you see any  terrain features?